# how is data skipping happening in d3js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

last item "8" in data is missing in output:

```
var data = [10, 15, 30, 50, 80, 65, 55, 30, 20, 10, 8];
 function render(data){

 d3.select("body")
   .data(data)
   .enter()
   .append("div")
   .attr("class", "h-bar")
   .append("span");

d3.selectAll("span")
  .data(data)
  .append("text")
  .text(function(d){
   return d;
  });
d3.selectAll("div")
  .data(data)
  .style("width", function(d){
    return d*5+ "px";
  });

 }

 render (data);
```

here is jsfiddle for this :http://jsfiddle.net/devprashant/E3aNd/

Answer (score 1):

You are binding data to the body right now I think it should be bound to the bar divs like:

`d3.select("body").selectAll(".h-bar")` This yields a selector for all elements with the class `.h-bar` instead of a selector for the `body` tag.

Also, because of [how selections work](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/selection/) in d3 you can simply do

```
 d3.select("body").selectAll(".h-bar")
   .data(data)
   .enter()
 .append("div")
   .attr("class", "h-bar")
   .style("width", function(d){
     return d*5+ "px";
    })
 .append("span")
    .text(function(d){
      return d;
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not repeat the data method, only one call is needed :

```
d3.selectAll("span")
// .data(data)
 .append("text")
 .text(function(d){
  return d;
 });
d3.selectAll("div")
 //.data(data)
 .style("width", function(d){
   return d*5+ "px";
 });
```

I made an update on your fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/E3aNd/1/

Comment: as per documentation, it does not matters how many times we made this selection if syntax is correct. then why its happening here.

Comment: No clue... sorry. I'll let you know if I find something.

Comment: The first data call needs to be bound to selection of divs (empty initially), not to body.

Answer (score 0):

```
   d3.select("body")
     .selectAll("div") // <-- bind data to divs, not to body
     .data(data)
     .enter()
     .append("div")
     .attr("class", "h-bar")
     .append("span");
```

You are missing .selectAll("div") before calling .data(data) in your first bind. The first call to data needs to be bound not to body, but to selection of divs, which will initially be empty.

To answer your question:

Your code is not including the *first* item on the initial pass. Then on subsequent data calls it's not including the last item because it's one div short. It's easy to see once you add text element to display value to the *initial* pass - http://jsfiddle.net/E3aNd/6/

Comment: original code is not including only the last item. See the attached jsfiddle